# jqGrid grid unload

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the GridUnload method to unload my original grid. Actually I want to load a grid depending on various conditions. Here I first call the GridUnload method and then call trigger on it to reload the grid with a new data. But in a browser, I get an error saying "Object doesn't support this property"  at the line where I call the GridUnload method. Is there anything else other than including the script in the head to use this method?

Comment: Can you post your code, to help us track this one down?

Comment: It is also good if you post the HTML code where one could see the order of loading of all JavaScripts which use use. The best results you will receive if you post full code which can be used to reproduce your problem. The version number of jqGrid which you use is sometime also helpfull to know.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. Actually I had not included the script 'grid.custom.js' in the HTML head.

When I did that, it worked fine :)

Comment: You welcome! Almost always errors like "Object doesnt support this property" mean that some JaveScript was not loaded (not included or included with the wrong path) or the order of the JaveScript files are wrong. Best witches for the future.